# What's the best way to set two range dates with a month of difference?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to render a view that show some records between two dates, when no parameter is passed the view must show the records of one month starting the 5th day until next 5th day of the next month.

right now i did it, but i'm concerned about my code, is there another way to do this i mean, get my code to look better.

```
var dateStart = new DateTime();
var dateEnd = new DateTime();

if(dateTime !=null)
{  
     dateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
     dateEnd = new DateTime(dateStart.Year, dateStart.Month + 1, 5);
}
else
{
     if (DateTime.Today.Day <= 4)
     {
          DateTime lastMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
          dateStart = new DateTime(lastMonth.Year, lastMonth.Month, 5);
          dateEnd = new DateTime(dateStart.Year, dateStart.Month + 1, 5);
     }

     DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
     dateStart = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 5);
     dateEnd = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month + 1,5);
}
```

Comment: You might also want to check whether the code is correct.  Have you tested it?

Comment: Your else-part doesn't work. You are always overriding the values calculated in the `if (DateTime.Today.Day <= 4)` part with the date calculated from `DateTime.Today`.

Comment: What is the [entity-framework] tag for?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I disagree, using this method in December will give you 13 for month, which will cause a "un-representable DateTime" exception

Comment: @GertArnold Removed that tag sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add on months like that as you'll end up with invalid `DateTime` come December when it tries to create a DateTime that has a month of 13, so I'd use the `AddMonths` method instead.  You also appear to need another `else statement` adding so that the second `if statement` isn't irrelevant. I've simplified the code slightly, was this what you meant?

```
var dateStart = new DateTime();
var dateEnd = new DateTime();

if(dateTime !=null)
{  
     dateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
     dateEnd = new DateTime(dateStart.Year, dateStart.Month, 5).AddMonths(1);
}
else
{
     if (DateTime.Today.Day <= 4)
     {
          dateStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 5).AddMonths(-1);
          dateEnd = dateStart.AddMonths(1);
     }
     else
     { 
          dateStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 5);
          dateEnd = dateStart .AddMonths(1);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction adding the months i didn't think about that!

Answer (score 1):

This will throw an exception come December:

```
dateEnd = new DateTime(dateStart.Year, dateStart.Month + 1, 5);
```

You might try:

```
DateTime dateEnd = dateStart.AddMonths(1);
dateEnd = new DateTime(dateEnd.Year, dateEnd.Month, 5);
```